# Default decode in utf-8 in suds

Tags: python, decode, suds

I had problems with coding with database name in Suds. This problem is solved in:

[Python unicode Decode Error SUDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953651/python-unicode-decode-error-suds)

The solution is to add decode('utf-8') after the property, like below

```
soap_fabric = soap.Fabric(
    color=article.color.decode('utf-8')
    articleNumber=shop_article.shop_article_nr,        
    supplier=article.supplier.name.decode('utf-8'),
    pluginFabricMemo.decode('utf-8')
```

I don't like to add this by each property. Does somebody know how to solve this issue beter?

Comment: Where do you get `article` from?

Comment: I'd like to expand on Simeon's question: suds should get only unicode strings. It seems that the values you are feeding into suds (`article.color`) use some other encoding (presumably UTF-8). As you mention "database name" you might retrieve these from your database. So the solution in that case is to tell your ORM to convert everything with UTF-8 before returning the data. sqlalchemy can do this. If this doesn't help please explain your context a bit better.